# Variance-stabilizing transformation on a simple linear regression

Tags: statistics, transformation, variance, regression-analysis

I am currently working with variance-stabilizer method and readed something about it from my textbook. I want to understand it better so I would like to consider a case where I for instance have a simple linear regression, let's say I have a model with response $y$, intercept and explanatory variable $x$, that is,
$$y_k=\beta_0+\beta_1x_k+\epsilon_k, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k=1,...,n.$$
with the residual variance proportional to the square of $x_k$: $V(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2x^2_k$. Then I would take the following as data transformation:
$$\tilde{y}_k:=\frac{y_k}{x_k} \text{ and } \tilde{x_k}:=\frac{1}{x_k}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; k=1,...,n.$$
Here is what I don't understand. The first thing is: Can I say something about the above is indeed a variance-stabilizing transformation? Second: Can I say something about the parameters from the models with original or transformed data related
to each other?

I've found examples of variance-stabilizing transformation on wikipedia where they use integrals and so on, but I cannot se how it could be applied in my example. I hope anyone can help me to better understand the variance-stabilizing transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the division by $x_k$, the model becomes
$$
\tilde{y}_k=\beta_0\tilde{x}_k+\beta_1+\tilde{\epsilon}_k,
$$
where $\tilde{\epsilon}_k:=\epsilon_k/x_k$. Assuming that $x_k$'s are non-stochastic,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\tilde{\epsilon}_k)=\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_k/x_k)=\frac{\sigma^2x_k^2}{x_k^2}=\sigma^2.
$$
This is a particular case of [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares).

Comment: Thank you! So I believe it relates to my second question because I see that it is not a variance-stabilizing transformation. 

My textbook mentioned something with weighted least squares which also are provied in your link. Let's say I have $w_k=1/x_k^2$ I am not sure but would it then be equivalent to my above considered transformation? Or do i need $w_k=1/x_k$? 

I am relative new to statistics like this, so I am glad that you help me.

Comment: The weights $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ should be chosen in a way that makes the variance of the new error term constant. In your case, $w_k=1/x_k$. In general, when $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2 f(x_k)$, one sets $w_k=1/\sqrt{f(x_k)}$.

Comment: BTW, WLS is a special case of GLS.

Comment: Okay, hmm. But if I use $w_k=1/x_k^2$ then I get something similar to my original problem, i.e. $Var(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2x_k^2$?

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Var}(w_k\epsilon_k)=w_k^2\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2x_k^2/x_k^4$ in that case.

Comment: I just try to understand because my lecture notes said that $Var(Y_k)=\sigma^2/w_k$ so that's why I think that I could just set $w_k=1/x_k^2$ and then arrive at the same as in my example. However I see that in my example I have $Var(\epsilon_k)=\sigma^2x_k^2$.